# How do I call a function in JavaScript on a specific file?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

```
var handleFileSelect;
handleFileSelect=function(e){
    n=new FileReader;
    n.onload=function(e){
    localStorage.settings = e.target.result
    },
    n.readAsText(this.files[0])
},

document.getElementById("settings_file").addEventListener("change",handleFileSelect,!1);
```

So, for the code above, when a User uploads a .Json file, handleFileSelect is then activated on that file.

I would like to change this so that there is no longer any need for the user to upload a file. What I mean is that I would like handleFileSelect to run on a .Json file which I have in the same folder as this .js file.

I feel like this is an easy thing to do, but I know no JavaScript whatsoever.

Thank you all for taking the time to read this.

I am coding this for a chrome extension that I am making.

Edit: How could I call the handleFileSelect function on a certain string of characters?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, it will never be possible for you to read from the user's local disk unless the user explicitly gives you the file.

Comment: Is it possible to read from a string of text?
Like say if I create a variable x and set it equal to a certain string of characters?